# How to open pdf in new pdf instance from a link in pdf

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, itext

I am using itext to write a pdf.In the pdf there are links to other pdf in the same dir but destination pdf is getting opened in the same pdf instance and original pdf is getting replaced in kpdf.I want both of my pdf remained opened.I am using the following code for the link to pdf

```
int PageNo = getEvidencePageNo( evidence );
PdfAction pdfAction = new PdfAction( actionPath 
+ File.separator + filename,PageNo );
chunk = new Chunk( folder.getName(), font ).setAction( pdfAction );
```

I am not sure if it is possible.If it is,please let me know the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.Setting is to be changes in acorbat reader in edit->preference->document.still finding the solution for kpdf and document viewer in linux.